# How do I save the data into a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I still new in python and have a question here: how could I store the variables outside and to use it later?

I have already created a class and in that class can store variables, for example, the `temp_username`, how do I get the `temp_username` and use it outside of the class?

```
def read_username(self):
    temp_username = self.username_entry.get()
    temp_username1 = self.username_entry1.get()
    if temp_username == '':
        print("No valid name")
        return
    else:
        self.name_valid = True
        self.username = temp_username
        self.username1 = temp_username1
```

Comment: Remainder: *Please don't post questions and delete after getting some answers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with local variables inside a function. What you would need is to transform that local variable into a global one.

A way to do that is using parameters and return:

```
def read_username(name):
    temp_username = name
    if temp_username == '':
        print("No valid name")
        return
    else:
        return temp_username

temp_username = read_username("ww")
print(temp_username)
```

Comment: Thank you so much and I appreciate your help! =D

Comment: How about the self paramater should i replace it with name?

Comment: Because I need to get the word the has been input in an entry widget